# linq to entities cannot convert type Icollection to type List

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework.
I have the following entities:

```
public class Articolo
{
    ..
    public virtual ICollection<Fornitore> Fornitori { get; set; }
}

public class Fornitore
{
  ...
   public virtual ICollection<Articoli> Articoli { get; set; }    }
```

the following code:

```
List<Fornitore> result = new List<Fornitore>();
var r = zefiroContext.Articoli.Where(p => p.Id == IdArticolo).Select(p => p.Fornitori).ToList();
result = r;
```

gives a compiler error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List <
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection < prova2.Model.Fornitore>>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List < prova2.Model.Fornitore>'

how can I get my `List < Fornitore >` ?

Answer (score 4):

Well you are actually trying to select multiple collections and I think that is where your problem is, changing your `Select` to `SelectMany` may resolve the issue for you but I am not sure if that is your intended functionality. What is going to happen is the `SelectMany` is going to condense all the individual result sets into a single collection which then can be turned into a list of the model type vs a list of collections of the model type.

```
var r = zefiroContext.Articoli.Where(p => p.Id == IdArticolo).SelectMany(p => p.Fornitori).ToList();
```

Comment: Each Articolo has Many Fornitori - So you're getting a list of lists... (Actually, a list of collections)

Comment: Also could be the Op intended `.First().Fornitori.ToList()` instead of .SelectMany(p => p.Fornitori)`

Answer (score 0):

Each Articolo has Many Fornitori - So you're getting a list of lists...

You may be meaning to get only the matching single item with a matchign id...

```
var r = zefiroContext.Articoli.First(p => p.Id == IdArticolo).Select(p => p.Fornitori).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot 'First' worked fine: var r = zefiroContext.Articoli.First(p => p.Id == IdArticolo).Fornitori.ToList();

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider [accepting this as the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if it solved your problem. You should also look into `Single()` which will throw an exception if more or less than 1 result is returned (if 0 or 2+ match the Id field). `SingleOrDefault()` will accept 0 or 1 results. `FirstOrDefault()` will accept any number of results. All will return only a single object (or null on no results if allowed)